# How to seal sump pit with removable cover

Tags: sump-pump

Just moved into a new house and bought new sump pump with battery backup.

The old pit liner is about 4" below floor level and the pit is 16" wide. the top is a mess as you can see from pix.

I want a rim/dome that seals to the concrete and a removable lid. Only needs one pipe coming out (y for backup and main are in pit (zoeller propack)

My problem is, the out diameter of the entire assembly cannot be more than 20 inches because of two stud walls.

Attached are a few pix (with the old pump still installed.

Any suggestions/recommended products?

Thanks

Mark

[image: Image1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Two pieces of outdoor-rated plywood with appropriate notches cut in them to allow pipe and pump shaft to come up between them would be a simple low-tech solution. It wouldn't "seal" unless you added weatherstripping or something like that, but it would do 90% of the job for 10% of the cost...

Answer (score 3):

I am currently doing the same thing; while sealing it for a radon system.  The radon pipe will be through the slab in a separate spot in the basement.  I am using a piece of clear Lexan with rubber foam rope insulation underneath it.

Here is my finished cover.  It works fantastically.  Access hole with removable seal.  Uniseals for the cords and pipe.

[image]

Comment: Nice setup, but OP doesn't have a clean, flat mounting surface like you did. Suggestions?

Comment: Not sure on unlevel mounting surface; maybe larger weather stripping?  The suction the radon fan creates is amazing.  When I pull the cord seal, wow; the air that gets pulled in is crazy.  I have a suburb home with nice gravel under my slab.

I would estimate my system would have been quoted at $1500-2000.  I did it for $450.  The sump pump is in a far corner sealed off.  The radon pipe enters the slab elsewhere, runs into my garage through the rim joist, up a garage corner in to my garage attic (where the fan is located) and out a gable vent.

Comment: As far as help, Val was a TREMENDOUS help.  His site is http://www.indoor-air-health-advisor.com/diy-radon-mitigation.html and his prices were lower than anywhere else.  I got the radon supplies and my sump pump cover supplies from his store.  I am not associated with him in any way.  I bombarded him with questions via email and he was very kind to guide me along the way.

Comment: Can you share more details on the rubber foam rope installation and it also looks like you have screws as well. How did you put those in and with what? Thanks

Comment: I just drilled holes and used plastic anchors with screws.

Comment: I think leveling could be done with vinyl concrete repair patch. I used the foam rubber seal with self adhesive and screwed right through it after drilling pilot holes.